# Размер экранна

Tags: android

Я понимаю, что вопрос не много глупый, но раньше не писал для планшетов.
Как назвать папку для `layout`?
Размер 9,7 дюймов
Разрешение: `2048 * 1536 IPS`
реального девайса под рукой нет, как я понимаю нужен что то вроде `layout-xhdpi` ?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А какой у него dpi?

Comment: http://www.ainol-novo.com/ainol-novo9-spark-quad-core-9-7-inch-retina-screen-ram-2gb-dual-camera-16gb.html вот под такой девайс будет вестись разработка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем [DPI Calculator](http://members.ping.de/~sven/dpi.html), считаем DPI.

Дальше открываем [Офф. Доку](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), и смотрим по схеме.

Answer (score 1):

Советую обратиться к [официальной документации](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/practices/screens_support.html)